# Cannot use GLOB with JSHint in Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jshint, build-tools

I'm doing a PoC of NPM as a build tool (http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/).  I'm fairly new using NPM.  For now, I only have JSHint and Mocha installed.  My packagae.json is attached.  Now, when I run "npm run lint" in the command line (Windows 7), it gives me an error:

```
c:\project>npm run list
MyNPMProject@1.0.0 lint c:\project
jshint test/*.js
```

> ERROR: Can't open test/*.js

It works when I change the script "lint": "jshint test/test.js".

Can I use glob with jshint?

Please advise and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't need the glob, just give  it the directory and it will scan all js files in there.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, with your example that would be `jshint test` or else `cd test` followed by `jshint .`, since `.` means 'current directory'.

Comment: Exactly, my preference would probably be the former but either should work.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to use a wildcard that can recurse down into subfolders, such as `test/**.js`, the basic Windows shell (Command Prompt) doesn't support that, but there are various workarounds/alternatives. See this for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114333/1593924